# What is a good way of retrieving/caching external facts using facter?

Tags: puppet, facter

All of our servers have attributes that we store in a database and I'd like to make these attributes available locally on each server for use by Puppet.  I don't want facter to query the database each time facter is run so using a facter executable script is probably not what I'm looking for.

I'm wondering if I should create a Puppet exec resource in my base module (that is used by all systems) that will query the database and store the values in /etc/puppetlabs/facter/facts.d/vars.yaml or something.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach?

Comment: Why don't you want to query the db? It seems more reasonable to query it directly instead of copying it's contents to some place which you will need to keep synchronized with the source from that point on...

Comment: It just seemed like a better way then having 1,000's of systems constantly querying the DB whenever they needed the information, particularly if the systems needed it dozens of times for its own checks (such as health monitoring)